# How does Notepad++ understands "last used directory" term?

Tags: notepad++, default-settings, save-as, files-folders, file-location

For the term of "*last used directory*" in Notepad++ I have these questions:

1. What is the exact meaning of in?
2. Exactly which directory will be taken as that each time?
3. When exactly Notepad++ changes this and to what value it sets this?

Or, please, explain what is that I don't understand in the following scenario.

Steps:

1. Set *Settings* → *Preferences* → *Default Directory* → *Default Open/Save file Directory* to *Remember last used directory*
2. Close and reopen Notepad++
3. Type anything and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
4. Observe that the directory is set to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`
5. Change it to something else (`C:\Trash` in my case)
6. Close and reopen Notepad++
7. Type anything and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
8. Observe that the directory is **still** set to `C:\Program Files\Notepad++`
9. Repeat steps 5-8 until the cold death of the universe.

What am I missing here? If my "last save operation" changed directory to `C:\Trash` then why Notepad++ is not using it as the "last used directory"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with Notepad++. It was previously resolved but it seems to be a problem once again as shown in these threads from Notepad++ community forum and Github respectively:

[Notepad++ does not remember last used directory](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17176/notepad-does-not-remember-last-used-directory)

["Default Directory" preference no longer works since the 7.95 release #9767](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/9767)

The possible fix that you can try/use for now is either:

1. To wait for the developer(s) to solve the problem
2. To find and use and older version of Notepad++